# How to set content of text control in screencode

Tags: text, controls, visual-studio-lightswitch

I just can't believe how hard this is.

I would like to edit the content of a Control with Type text. I'm working with lightswitch visual studio 2012. I would like to change this in the screencode (so programmatic).

I gave the control the name: "Message".

Right now, I'm trying `this.FindControl("Message").`, but there doesn't seem to be any property I can call to set the content. Nether can I cast the control to the correct Type text. Even Text doesn't seem to be a valid className.

Any Help on how to set the content of this control?

**EDIT:** Should I shoot the `ControlAvailable` event and try to modify content there?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with this.FindControl("Message").  The way to set a property on it once you have found it is as follows:

```
this.FindControl("Message").SetProperty("propertyToSet", [new value])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, trying to set the value of a control on a screen is the **wrong** way to do it.

In LightSwitch, every control is bound to a property (usually an entity's property, but might also be a screen property), so setting the value of that property will update the control.

So if you have a detail screen that is bound to an entity (let's call it *ClientProperty*), & you have a *TextBox* control (let's call it *MessageControl*) bound to *ClientProperty*'s *Message* property, all your code needs to do to change the value is:

```
Me.ClientProperty.Message = "This is a message"
```

If instead, you had a *TextBox* control (again, let's call it *MessageControl*) that's bound to a screen property (called *Message*), your code is as simple as:

```
Me.Message = "This is another message"
```

It seems "hard" the way you're trying to do it because it's not meant to be done that way.